# Every time array list overrides the old values. How can I insert new values to array?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arraylist

I’m creating a simple cafe purchase module for an app, for a specific set of users, in android studio (java) using firebase.
In which, I have the user list under which a field called “cafeTrans” is specified to get the “datewise” purchases of the user. I want to record the bill amount of every purchases. made by the user. I have created a list and everytime the user purchases something the old values are getting overridden. I want to save every purchase amount.

What to do? Could someone help me as to what to do?
I would much appreciate the help. Been pondering over this for almost a week now, since I’m a newbie.

**Function Code:**

```
cafeTransList = new ArrayList<>(); // Initiated at onCreate


public void uploadBillAmount(){

    cafeTransListLevel = userLevel.child("cafeTrans").child("20211127");

    cafeTransList.add(String.valueOf(billAmtInt));


    cafeTransListLevel.setValue(cafeTransList).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                Log.i("Data Added", String.valueOf(billAmtInt));

            }
        }
    });
}

**userLevel indicates the DB node of the individual user
**billAmtInt indicates the purchase value
```

**My User Model Class:**

```
public class User {

    private String lastUpdate, username, level, score, busNo, email, cash, dailylimit;
    private List<String> cafeTransList;


    public User(String lastUpdate, String username, String level, String score, String busNo, String email, String cash, String dailylimit, List<String> cafeTransList) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
        this.username = username;
        this.level = level;
        this.score = score;
        this.busNo = busNo;
        this.email = email;
        this.cash = cash;
        this.dailylimit = dailylimit;
        this.cafeTransList = cafeTransList;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    public String getLastUpdate() { return lastUpdate; }

    public void setLastUpdate(String lastUpdate) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }


    public String getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void setLevel(String level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public String getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(String score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getBusNo() {
        return busNo;
    }

    public void setBusNo(String busNo) {
        this.busNo = busNo;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getCash() {
        return cash;
    }

    public void setCash(String cash) {
        this.cash = cash;
    }


    public String getDailylimit() {
        return dailylimit;
    }

    public void setDailylimit(String dailylimit) {
        this.dailylimit = dailylimit;
    }

    public List<String> getcafeTransList() {
        return cafeTransList;
    }

    public void setcafeTransList(List cafeTransList) {
        this.cafeTransList = cafeTransList;
    }
}
```

***My DB Structure:***

```
“User-ID XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX” : {
      "busNo" : "2",
      "cafeTrans" : 
        {
        "20211127" : [ "10" ] // this list values are getting overridden every time a new purchase is made for the date.
        },
      "cash" : "30",
      "dailylimit" : "0",
      "email" : "a@b.com",
      "lastUpdate" : "20211209",
      "level" : "6",
      "score" : “0”
      "username" : "Demo"
```

Answer (score 1):

To add an item to an array, you must know the number of existing items that are in that array. So you will first have to read the existing items from the database, then add an item to the array in code, and then finally write the resulting array (or just the new item by its index) back into the database.

This is quite inefficient, which is why Firebase recommends against using array structures for list, and instead provides its own built-in `push()` method that generates unique, always-incrementing keys. For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [adding an item to a list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data).

To learn more about why arrays are not a great data structure for Firebase, read Kato's classic article on [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).